# Run keyword at suite level only if the test cases in that suite pass when executed

Tags: robotframework

I need to run the keyword only if the test case passes.How can i setup it up at Test suit level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Suite Teardown, you can use the (automatic) variable `${SUITE_STATUS}`. This variable is document [in here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) and contains "The status of the current test suite, either PASS or FAIL". So it will contain PASS when all the test cases of the suite are passing.

Here is how it can be used:

```
my_suite_teardown
    Run Keyword If    '${SUITE_STATUS}' == 'PASS'  your_keyword
```

Comment: We can also use "Run keyword if test passed" which is a ride level keyword

Comment: @OrsuSuni: there is no such thing as a "ride level keyword". RIDE is an IDE. It has no keywords.

Comment: Sorry !! I am new to this. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in library has keywords specifically for this purpose.

You can call these keywords in a suite setup:

- [Run keyword if any test failed](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Any%20Tests%20Failed)
- [Run keyword if any critical tests failed](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Any%20Critical%20Tests%20Failed)

You can call these keywords in a test case teardown:

- [Run keyword if test failed](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Test%20Failed)
- [Run keyword if test passed](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Test%20Passed)

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Teardown   Perform test teardown
Suite Teardown  Perform suite teardown

*** Keywords ***
Perform suite teardown
    run keyword if any test failed
    ...  log  "Hey, this suite failed!"  WARN

Perform test teardown
    run keyword if test failed
    ...  log  "Hey, this test failed!"  WARN
```

Suite and test case teardowns are described in the robot framework user guide in a section titled [Setups and teardowns](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setups-and-teardowns).